# Python How to get portuguese char from web

Tags: python

I want to read from my website the discription of the page. Here is the code

```
import urllib.request
import re
req = urllib.request.Request("http://sorelogios.pt", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})        
htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
if htmltext is None:
    print("nada")
else:
    regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    price=pattern.findall(str(htmltext))    
    print(price[0])
    regex='<meta name="description" content=(.+?)/>'
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    prices=pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
    print(prices[0])
```

My problem is my webpage has portuguese char and I get something like 
rel\xc3\xb3gios homem loja online
How can I solve this issue and get the original chars?
Thank you

Comment: Don't use `str()`, *decode*. If you were to use a proper HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) rather than regex matches, you'd get Unicode results back for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the response.

```
htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you for point me in  the right direction but I got a litle problem: If you run it because the char \\r\\n\\t I got empty result